# Read the text file and split into multiple files based unique code present in the first column

Tags: python, pandas

Read the text file and split into multiple files based on the unique code present in the first column of text file- Column structure will be different for each record based on the unique code identifier in first column.

Text file with comma separator

```
Sample input file structure
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "CA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY"
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY", "123", "567", "888"
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA", "123", "567", "999"
```

I would like to split the above text file into text file based on the unique code identifier in the first column.

Expected two file with data as below

```
File1
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "CA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY"

file2
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY", "123", "567", "888"
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA", "123", "567", "999"
```

Note: As structure of different for each code identifier, I'm not able to read the data into pandas dataframes

Answer (score 1):

You question contain two parts,1st read the file with unbalanced row , then split the dataframe to sub-dfs

```
import pandas, io

data = io.StringIO('''"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "CA"
"05555", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY"
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "NY", "123", "567", "888"
"0666666", "AB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "USA", "123", "567", "999"
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data,sep=';',header=None)
s=df[0].str.split(',',expand=True)
s=s.apply(lambda x : x.str.strip(' "'),1)
for x , y in s.groupby(0):
    print(y.dropna(1))
    y.dropna(1).to_csv(str(x)+'.csv')
       0   1   2   3   4    5
0  05555  AB  CC  DD  EE  USA
1  05555  AB  CC  DD  EE   CA
2  05555  AB  CC  DD  EE   NY
         0   1   2   3   4    5    6    7    8
3  0666666  AB  CC  DD  EE   NY  123  567  888
4  0666666  AB  CC  DD  EE  USA  123  567  999
```

Comment: Thank you. data = io.StringIO you passing entering string but i have huge volume of data , Is any way to read the data from file.

Comment: @Pete that is hard, since unbalance data , you may not want to read it by row , so I read them into one columns , then using pandas modify it

Comment: Ok. Thank you @ WenNYoBen

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` and an `for` loop and then write the `csv`s:

```
for i, (_, group) in enumerate(df.groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]), 1):
    group.to_csv('File%s' % i)
```

Comment: First, I'm not able to read the data into dataframe as I'm getting the parsing error as the number of columns are different for  each code identifier